How to pass children to react native action sheet?
react native action sheet
How to pass children to Action sheet?
export default function Drawer({ children }: DrawerProps) {
        ...
    return (
        <ActionSheet
            CustomHeaderComponent={DrawerHeader}
            headerAlwaysVisible={true}
            containerStyle={styles.actionSheetContainer}>
            <View style={styles.contentContainer}>{children}</View>
        </ActionSheet>
    );
}

I was looking for something like this. I have a couple of content views so I thought of creating a single drawer and then passing my content inside of this drawer but it doesn't seem to work like this :(
<Drawer>
    <MyContent />
</Drawer>

